# Get value from data set and populate in another data set

Tags: angular

I have the following data set which when I console.log out, I get the correct data however when I try to add it to another array it shows as undefined

```
dim.dimensions.push({"width": "100", "height": "100"});
console.log(dim.dimensions[0].width); //value comes through correctly here

this.dataArr = [
  {
    "name": ctx.files_dropped[i].name, 
    "size": ctx.files_dropped[i].size, 
    "type": ctx.files_dropped[i].type, 
    "modified": ctx.files_dropped[i].lastModified, 
    "width": dim.dimensions[0]?.width //undefined here
 }
];
```

These arrays are declares as follows

```
  dimensions: any = [];
  dataArr: any = [];
```

Any idea why this is happening? Here is an image of how it consoles out [image]

Comment: Can you post your full component or method thats having the issue?  Seems like one of your blocks might be in an async call which is why its not defined when you try to use it in `this.dataArr`

Comment: @cjd82187 Please see my stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

Comment: The image function is asynchronous which is your problem. I'll add an fixed one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See updated stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-r78yda

You had quite a few issues which I addressed in comments, mostly scoping issues which is why you couldn't use `this`, and your use of `var i` in your for loop made `i` undefined in the new event listener.

Also, the `reader.addEventListener` method is asynchronous so your other method was running before the event listener ran.

Full component incase stackblitz goes down:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  files_dropped: File[] = [];
  dimensions: any = [];
  dataArr: any = [];


onSelect(event) {

  this.dimensions = [];
  this.files_dropped.push(...event.addedFiles);
  // use let, not var so we can access `i` inside the event listenr
  for (let i = 0; i < this.files_dropped.length; i++) {
    
    const reader = new FileReader();
    // Note the arrow function here, this allows proper scoping so you can still use `this` instead of setting other variables to this.
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const img = document.createElement("img") as HTMLImageElement;
      img.onload = () => {
        this.dimensions.push({"width": img.naturalWidth, "height": img.naturalHeight});
        console.log(this.dimensions[0].width);

        // this whole event listner is async, so this data array needs to be done inside here or else it runs before the event listener and will be undefined.
        this.dataArr = [
          {
            "name": this.files_dropped[i].name, 
            "size": this.files_dropped[i].size, 
            "type": this.files_dropped[i].type, 
            "modified": this.files_dropped[i].lastModified, 
            "width": this.dimensions[0].width
        }
        ];
        console.log(this.dataArr);

      }
      img.src = reader.result as string;
    }, false);
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files_dropped[i]);
    
  }

}

onRemove(event) {
  console.log(event);
  this.files_dropped.splice(this.files_dropped.indexOf(event), 1);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, help and explanation. Helped me a lot!